# How to access 'http' on android 30?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, android-volley, okhttp

I'm trying to access 'http://' on Android api 30, but I can only access https using 'com.android.volley:1.2.1' and 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'.
I can access http when using 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.11.0'.
What's the reason?

Other settings are as follows.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
          ....
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

1. There is no http connection from Android api 30 to retrofit2, volley, and https access is possible.
2. I can access http from Android api 27 to retrofit2, volley.
3. With okhttp3 on Android api 30, http access is possible.

Comment: Remove the network security config. Add a uses clear text traffic true.

Comment: Oh, my.... I'm sorry, but let me ask you one more question... If I delete network security config, how to I connect only to a specific port?

Comment: Why would you? What would it bring?

Comment: I only want to allow access to http://localhost:8080 tomcat server within the same network.

Comment: Where would your app try to use a different port? Or ip-port?

Comment: this is ip port ----> ex) http://192.xxx.xxx.205:8080/~~

Comment: In network security config you specify domains (DNS names or IP addresses), thus the port is wrong, remove it. Please see the examples on https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/security-config

Comment: Verry thank you, solved it.